# Complement of a language

Tags: automata, turing-machines

$L$ = $\{\langle M \rangle \mid \text {M is a TM, M accepts some string that ends with } 101\}$.

What would the complement for this be?

$\bar{L}$ = $\{\langle M \rangle \mid \text {M is a TM, M accepts all strings that ends with } 101\}$.

is my guess

Comment: You can easily see that cannot be the complement, because a machine that accepts _everything_ would be in both languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L = \{\langle M \rangle$ | $M$ is a TM, M accepts $some$ string that ends with 101 $\}$

$\bar L = \{\langle M \rangle$ | $M$ is a TM, M does not accept $any$ string that ends with 101 $\}$